# JSQMessagesViewController stops calling cellForItemAtIndexPath after several messages

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I have a bit of a weird issue with a messaging app that users JSQMessagesViewController. It all works fine but if I send a bunch of media messages in quick succession the UICollectionView stops calling cellForItemAtIndexPath so all the cells disappear :/ I have checked the sizeForItem and the cell size is consistent and the height of the scroll area increases if more messages are sent. Checking other UICollectionViewDataSource methods all the other ones I checked are called so I don't really understand why this suddenly stops working.

Why would this method suddenly not be called when the rest is all behaving the same? Has anyone else had this with a collectionview in general or specifically with JSQMessagesViewController?

Comment: If you found any solution, Please suggest.